# Google cloud messaging in chrome browser: does chrome itself have to be open to receive gcm?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging

I am not sure if the Chrome browser itself must be open to receive google cloud messages on a laptop.
I know that my chrome extension does not need to be open, but what about Chrome itself?

I'd like my user to be able to receive google cloud messages through Chrome as long as their laptop is on.

I know Safari push notifications will be received even if Safari is not running.  Is this true for Chrome google cloud messages too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes Chrome must be running. However Chrome runs differently on Windows if there are background app.